# Find the Row which contain only row with zero and One for the Particular data

Tags: sql, join, row, rank

I have data where group will one row as zero and one and for the same data value will give one and two.

[image]

I have tried with below code .which seems to be not working

```
select *
from (select livecasnum, flag,
             DENSE_RANK()over (partition by livecasnum order by flag) as Ranks
      from TblcaseFlag
      group by livecasnum, flag
     ) b
 group by livecasnum,flag,Ranks
 having count(flag + Ranks) = 1 and flag <> 1
```

I need only like data one row which having only zero and one ex: 99149

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `not exists` instead :

```
select tf.*
from TblcaseFlag tf
where tf.flag = 0 and
      not exists (select 1 
                  from TblcaseFlag tf1 
                  where tf.livecasnum = tf1.livecasnum and 
                        tf1.flag = 1
                 );
```

Comment: Thank you Yogesh sharma and Gordon linoff it worked . so for comparing row by row we need to use where xyz=xyz and particular condition . Thank you once again